# Почему в windows XP эта команда прерывает обработку сценария?

Tags: windows, файлы, консоль, bat

Есть такой батник:

```
@<"info.txt">"out.txt" (for /f "delims=" %%i in ('find/n /v ""') do @chcp 65001>nul& set x=%%i& cmd/v/c echo[!x:*]^^=!)

pause
```

Он правильно конвертирует файл из CP866 в UNICODE. Но почему то он обрывает ввод сразу после своей работы (pause не отрабатывает). И эта проблема наблюдается только в XP версии windows, в семерке этой проблемы нет. В чем причина не пойму.

Comment: видимо потому, что внутри одного терминала Вы запускаете второй и похоже затирает первый.

Comment: @KoVadim а почему тогда в семерке этой проблемы нет? или подскажите как это правильно реализовать

Comment: правильный способ - использовать утилиты для конвертирования и запускать их. Или ещё лучше - пользоваться нормальными осями.

Comment: @KoVadim  я от xp не избавлюсь это есть в ТЗ и бесплатным софтом не имеющим соответствующую лицензию пользоваться не могу. Ищу дедовский велосипед.

Comment: тогда у Вас как минимум два варианта - забыть о ТЗ и уйти в другую компанию или написать отдельный батник, который будет получать один (два) параметра и делать только конвертацию файла. А уже отдельный батник будет запускать первый батник.